# Relation between vector surface integral and volume integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, divergence-operator

I tried to solve the surface integral of $I+j+k$ over a hemisphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ , but when I solved it using Gauss divergence theorem it comes to be 0 ? If one could explain.

Comment: A good textbook proof of Gauss' divergence theorem should tell you exactly how it works.

Comment: Welcome to mathstackexchange. Your answer does not match some quality standards: it is not mathjax, and you have not show your efforts to solve the problem (which are useful to others, since they can better undertand the question). Your question, more importantly, is not clear: in order do avoid downvotes or the closure ot the answer as it is unclear what you are asking, please be more specific. I recomand you to read https://math.stackexchange.com/tour. Again, welcome!

Comment: You say "hemisphere". Do you mean a hemisphere shell with, or without the flat bottom? And which hemisphere?

Comment: a shell with lying in x y plane

Comment: So the top half ($z\geq0$) of the unit sphere? And once again: is the bottom included?